# UI control to display data in the form of Grid

Tags: datagrid, uiviewcontroller

Is there any UI control which displays data in the form of grid?! And have the following features:

- I should be able to hide/unhide
  columns.
- A popup to show up on click of the
  header. The pop-up will behave like a filter. It will have all the unique values in that particular column. The user can select the values that are to be displayed.

Is there such control in JQuery/Flex/extJS or any other UI framework?

Thank You

**EDIT** I want to replicate the Excel in the Web UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Easy answer

Most of the commercially-available grids have this kind of stuff, but it depends what framework you're using.

[jQuery Grid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) is pretty cool and of course doesn't really rely on a back-end framework. If you're using .NET WebForms, check out offerings from Telerik and DevExpress. Telerik also have a ASP.NET MVC suite of stuff (which, I believe, is free).

### Devil's advocate

There is a school of thought that suggests grids aren't really a good UI. It's true that people love Excel, but even MS and Google are struggling to replicate Excel in a web UI (though they've done quite a good job). The reason WPF shipped without a datagrid is because the ListBox, when combined with DataTemplates, is soooooo much more powerful than a pre-prepared grid control that one wasn't really necessary.

One way out of this problem is to try and think your way out of needing a grid in the first place. Consider task based UI, and maybe CQRS, where the grid/reporting requirements are solved in a completely different way (e.g. SQL Server Reporting Services).